# Rigidbody ignores ground plane

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

This feels really basic, but it's messing with me.

I have a Plane as a passive Rigidbody floor [although I've switched it to Active, same result] and a cube I am animating on, then switching Dynamic on for and Animated off part way through it's movement so it the rest gets simulated

It works, but only until I set Mass on the object, then it decides to stop simulating movement, stop interacting with the Plane object and just fall.

Any idea what's going on? No variation of Active / Passive / Convex Hull / Mesh is helping.

[Edit]
File can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms4iypojwfssjpj/Layout_02_Fail.blend?dl=0
Thanks Ron Jensen for the suggestion.

Comment: Since this is not normal behavior, it will be very difficult for someone to answer as-is. Screenshots of your physics, collections, and world tabs might help. Sharing a blend file that shows the problem might help, too.

Comment: Well, it's nice to know it's not normal.

Here's a link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms4iypojwfssjpj/Layout_02_Fail.blend?dl=0

Blender 2.83.0

Comment: Its working for me, how do I make it fail? Oh, I'm using Blender 2.93.3

Comment: I pulled up my old copy of 2.83.0 and it is broken there.

Comment: It's working in my 2.93.5 as well. Is there a reason why you have to do it in 2.83.0? Do you have the problem in a newer version as well, or just the old one? If it's just the old one, you should give the version information in the question. It might be a bug then, but I doubt it will be removed from the old version.

Comment: Ah, I was using 2.83.0 because that's what's on my computer. Trying to commit to the leap from 3DS - long overdue. I ended up animating the effect by hand, like a pleb. Nice to know how to fix it though!

I have upgraded Blender now. I'll keep on top of it. Thanks so much for testing it and helping me out!